# Are questions related to the Photoshop user interface on macOS on topic?

Tags: discussion

Photoshop is constantly moving the window application on macOS when the menu bar overlaps it. The menu bar is set to hide automatically. This is a question about the Photoshop user interface and preferences, but also it could be something related to the system preferences, although I'd prefer not to have the menubar set to be always visible for the whole system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**NO**, this is clearly a tech support question since it is about the functioning of a graphic design program and not about what to accomplish with said program. Some tech questions can be suited to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com).

Look at it this way, if you have two people you could ask, which one would you ask?

- a computer whiz kid who knows everything about computer programs but nothing about graphic design
- a professional graphic designer who knows nothing about computer programs

If the answer is not the second one, then the question is not on topic here.

---

That said, there's an off chance someone here has experienced the same issue. You can always pop into [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) and ask the question. We're way more lenient there.

Comment: Nitpicking: The functioning of a graphic-design program is not off-topic per se, at least in my understanding of [this](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3300/19174). The crucial thing is that graphic designers can be expected to be more knowledgeable about the issue than general computer experts (which is your second paragraph). I agree with you that this is probably not the case here.

Comment: As I was re-reading my answer I had the same thought, which is why I added the second paragraph (inspired by the Q you linked).