# Is asking about how to setup a graphics drawing tablet also considered off-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I have a drawing tablet specifically for graphic design, and the default setting for one of the hotkeys is what I am trying to return the function to. I have searched online on how to do so and checked this brand's official website as well, but it only explained the basics of where to go in order to change things.

I did check [this page](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to see what would count as a fitting question which included "how to achieve something with design software", but I'm not sure if this exactly would be considered design software: It is a software that changes the settings of a graphic design drawing tablet, but not something like Adobe Photoshop. I also checked [this page](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/revisiting-closure-part-3-1-drawing-the-line-for-tech-support) to see whether my question falls under tech support but unlike issues such as "you will need more space in your drive" which is quite easy for anyone who does not necessarily know the software to answer or help with, mine may be an issue due to having an old version, not doing the setup for that specific tool properly, or anything that only others who most likely use/d the same product would understand.

Would these kinds of questions be considered off-topic or on-topic in this Stack Exchange? If it was off-topic, where should these be asked? If on-topic, what tags may we include?

Comment: you can ask offcourse but im not sure there will be a an answer that makes you happy. I mean it really depends on which tablet, which software and which OS. so it might be on topic or it might not be.

Answer (score 1):

This is a hard problem.

On the one hand, our on-topic litmus test is this: You are in an office with both a computer and hardware expert, and a professional designer. Who would you ask. If the answer is not the latter, it is not on topic.

Chances are that a professional designer would have much more experience with drawing tablets, which is kinda niche hardware. So it would make sense to ask them, making your question on-topic.

On the other, it most definitely is a hardware question, and a very specific one at that. Even though professional designers are probably more experienced with drawing tablets overall, there is but a small chance they'll have experience with this brand or this one in particular.

We are a stack for solving design problems, not hardware issues. That would make the question off-topic.

**Conclusion**:  There is something to say for both on- and off-topic. My suggestion would be to ask away, and see how the community reacts. Maybe you'll find someone with some experience with this specific tablet brand/model. Don't be surprised if your question gets closed however.

---

As to where you should ask if not here: The manufacturer. There is no stack for hardware support, because that's what manufacturers should be doing.

Comment: Might be fitting on https://apple.stackexchange.com/ -- No clue if there's something similar for Windows.