# Should we burninate [behance]?

Tags: discussion, tags, burnination

Of the 7 questions tagged with [behance](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behance) exactly 0 are useful to the community.

[One](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/118390/cut-one-big-horizontal-artwork-to-multiple-different-artwork-in-illustrator) is not necessarily related to behance and [the other](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/68956/strange-gif-artifacts-when-uploading-to-behance) is about artifacts when uploading an image to the service (I'm sure there's a dupe somewhere). All the other questions are closed as off-topic.

Should we then burninate this tag?

Comment: I say go for it. Same with [dribbble](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dribbble) btw.

Comment: Aye. *raises hand to attain the character limit*

Answer (score 3):

No I don't think we should or dribble for that matter. These questions are on topic and relevant to graphic designers. They may not be the most interesting questions but we're here to answer questions pertaining to graphic design and these are that. Referencing nearly all of our on-topic principles the consensus is usually [best summarized here by user568458](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1102/2611) which states, "Would I ask this to a graphic designer?" I believe you would ask a graphic designer how to get a quality upload to an online platform.

It's like we have questions about [Facebook](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=Facebook) usually regarding image quality and resolution.

These are the mediums graphic design work now exists and we should be open to helping designers understand these mediums.

Perhaps a better option would be to rethink the tagging. Change Dribble, Coroflot, Behance, Facebook, etc into "Web Display" or "Online Medium" or something to that effect.

Comment: Maybe a [social-media] tag - even the Facebook questions don't have a [facebook] tag. Problem is that most of these questions are either common to all (and already asked) or specific to each platform, and there are guidelines for image quality in the platforms themselves. People just don't read it, and I wouldn't like to see GD become the instruction manual of these platforms.

Comment: @Luciano Is Behance or Coroflot "social media?" - and to your second point... printers and print shops and even the software used all have manuals and guidelines as well.

Comment: duh! Never mind, I was thinking of the facebook/instagram questions. maybe [online-medium] or [online-platforms] then?

Comment: But should we replicate what's already easily available on official product manuals? Behance has a help center with guidelines for uploading images, so do Coroflot and Facebook, and Photoshop and Illustrator. I'm all for teaching a designer to fish, but how much fish should we _give away for free_?

Comment: @Luciano downvote the questions if you think its lazy